# How does Haskell compile zipper patterns?

Tags: haskell

"Learn You a Haskell" shows the following data type and then gives a bunch of [algorithms](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) that manipulate the trees using this.

```
data Crumb a = LeftCrumb a (Tree a) | Right Crumb a (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

Unlike imperative languages where something like binary search would be explained in terms of walking down pointers. Here there are no mentions of pointers. But how do algorithms like binary search get compiled down in Haskll? Do they compile down to the same efficient walking down pointers?

Comment: There's probably pointers involved.

Comment: [These slides](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/11au-cs240h/notes/memory-slides.html#%281%29) have some information on how such values are represented in Haskell.

Comment: Eh, if you're just learning Haskell **you don't want to know** laziness is a hairy beast to implement and the way haskell compilers optimize is scary still. Just accept it as nice and high level and come back to it once you've gotten the hang of Haskell

Comment: In a call by value setting Andrew Appel's CPS book gives a good idea.  [Edward Yang's post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/04/the-haskell-heap/) on the Haskell heap gives a good idea with laziness is involved.  (Then you scale up to strictness analysis, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

- **The Haskell language:** Compilers can do whatever they want to the code as long as it makes sense from the specification. This means that there can be pointer walking just like you'd expect in C, or there might not be. The language specification doesn't really care how the things are implemented, as long as they work like they are supposed to.
- **The GHC compiler:** If you really want to know how GHC compiles your code in the end, I suggest learning to read C-- (pronounced "C-minus-minus") or assembly. You can get GHC to spit out C-- code with `-ddump-cmm` and assembly with `-ddump-asm`. Unless you are planning to start work on optimising the compiler though, I don't think this would be a very useful exercise.

  As a general rule, imperative code GHC writes looks *very* different from what a human would write. So probably no pointers in the sense you're thinking of. (And the cool thing is that it works out efficiently in the end anyway!)